# Save a popup window to text using VBS

Tags: vbscript, popup, save, focus, text-files

I have created a code that will open Internet Explorer, navigate to a site, prompt for credentials and a date range, and then save the data (theoretically) to a text file.

Everything works except for saving the data. When I click their export button, it pops up a new window that is untitled (so I can't focus on the window by name) and when I try to save it to a .txt file it saves the 1st webpage that is still focused, not the popup window.

How do I shift focus to the popup window/save the popup to a text file?

Unfortunately I can't provide much code, but here is the code I am using to save to a text file:

```
TEXT = objIE.Document.Body.InnerText

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("Banorte.txt", 2, True)
ts.Write TEXT
ts.Close
```

Also, I don't have an option to download any software to help me with this. I am also not opposed to using a different language if need by, or call a separate script.

Thank you for taking a look!

------EDIT------

Here is some additional code, the site is banorte.com, this is the code that runs after I log in.

And by popup, I mean it opens up a new window in internet explorer, but it is not like a tab, that has a name and could be added to the parent window. It is a standalone.

```
objIE.Document.getElementsByName("btnEntrar").Item(0).Click

While objIE.Busy
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

objIE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$Contentplaceholder1$btnConsultar").Item(0).Click

WScript.Sleep 5000

objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Contentplaceholder1$grdCuentasCheques$ctl02$ctl00','')"


BEGDATE= InputBox("Please enter the beginning date DD/MM/YYYY:","Please provide additional info.")

objIE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_Contentplaceholder1_ucPeriodoFechas_WucFechaInicial_txtFecha").value = BEGDATE

ENDDATE= InputBox("Please enter the ending date DD/MM/YYYY:","Please provide additional info.")

objIE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_Contentplaceholder1_ucPeriodoFechas_WucFechaFinal_txtFecha").value = ENDDATE



objIE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$Contentplaceholder1$btnConsultar").Item(0).Click

WScript.Sleep 2000
```

Issue is after this command:

```
objIE.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$Contentplaceholder1$btnExportarSaldos").Item(0).Click

Do Until objIE.readystate = 4
 WScript.Sleep 10 
loop

TEXT = objIE.Document.Body.InnerText

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("Banorte.txt", 2, True)
ts.Write TEXT
ts.Close


objIE.Navigate "https://nbem.banorte.com/NBXI/Corporativa/Cerrar.aspx"

ObjIE.quit
```

Comment: What did you mean by popup ? we need more information and more code ! can you edit your post and post the code without your  credentials ?

Comment: Anybody have a solution or at least where to look next?